# How to match [BOF]"Begin of file" in Antlr4 Lexer?

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

In one Antlr4 syntax, I need the comment (`// xxxx`) to be always at the start of a line.
The following grammar works fine for most cases.

```
grammar com;

comment: COMMENT;

COMMENT
 : '\n' '//' .*? '\n'
 ;
```

By design, it will match `\n//comment\n` but not `//comment\n`. But I also want it to match `<BOF>//comment\n`. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

You may find that this edit is better handled post-parsing, in a semantic validation pass of your parseTree.  (NOTE: It's not a requirement that a parser ONLY recognize valid input, just that it correctly interprets the only way to understand that input.)

For example, does `// might be a comment` have some other, alternate interpretation if it's not at the beginning of the line?

If not, I would probably just accept the `// comment ...\n` as a token regardless of it's position in the line.

Then, once you have the parse tree, you can check that you `comment`s always have a column of 0.  Doing it this way, your grammar is not tied to a particular target language, and, perhaps more importantly, you can give a "nice" error message like "Comments must begin in the first column of a line".

If you try to handle this in the Lexer (or parser), then, if it's NOT in the correct column, you'll get a much more obtuse recognition error that will be more difficult for users to understand.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible in a language agnostic way. You will have to add target specific code in your grammar and use a predicate to check if the char position is 0:

```
COMMENT
 : {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? '//' ~[\r\n]*
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

If you now tokenize the input:

```
// start
// middle
?//...
// end
```

with the Java code:

```java
String input = "// start\n// middle\n?//...\n// end";
comLexer lexer = new comLexer(CharStreams.fromString(input));
CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
stream.fill();

for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s'%s'%n",
        comLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
        t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
}
```

the following will be printed to your console:

```
COMMENT   '// start'
OTHER     '\n'
COMMENT   '// middle'
OTHER     '\n'
OTHER     '?'
OTHER     '/'
OTHER     '/'
OTHER     '.'
OTHER     '.'
OTHER     '.'
OTHER     '\n'
COMMENT   '// end'
EOF       '<EOF>'
```

Note that I also removed the `\n` at the end of the `COMMENT`, otherwise a comment at the end of the input would not be matched.

#### EDIT

> How I can do it with JavaScript? I cannot find good examples on internet.

By looking at the [Javascript source](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/JavaScript/src/antlr4/Lexer.js), it looks like `{this.column === 0}?` is the Javascript equivalent of `{getCharPositionInLine() == 0}?`

> By the way, does the Intellij Plugin support predict? If it does, does it support only Java?

No, the IntelliJ plugin ignores predicates. After all, the code inside a predicate can be any arbitrary chunk of code, making it quite hard to support.

Comment: Thanks. How I can do it with JavaScript? I cannot find good examples on internet. By the way, does the Intellij Plugin support predict? If it does, does it support only Java?

Comment: @DevsloveZenUML checkout my EDIT

Comment: Thank you @bart-kiers, do you think `BOF` should be added as a feature to Antlr4? https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/4005#issuecomment-1345259651

Comment: It should be {this.column === 0}. I have updated your answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: You could do this in a language agnostic way using Lexer modes, but it would be a major pain because Antlr4 assumes that lexer modes are entirely independent, and thus doesn't provide any mechanism for specifying that a collection of rules are in more than one mode. It doesn't look to me like it would be so difficult to change the syntax of a mode from `"mode" id ";" rule*´ to `"mode" id ("," id)* ";" rule*`; the only thing needed is to keep a list of mode names instead of a single one, and then add each rule to all each of the modes. I think that would satisfy other use cases for modes, too.

Comment: I totally understand why it is difficult to support that in the Intellij Plugin. I need to support `if(x == y)`. Is there a good workaround or configuration that I can tell the plugin to ignore one parser or lexer rule, so it parse `if( x == y)` as expected?

Comment: No, you cannot influence the plugin.